# Select UIViewController directly from UITabBarController and via UINavigationController

Tags: swift, tabs, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar, segue

I start my App with a Tab Bar Controller [TBC]. I use one Item1 to select VC1 (embedded in a Navigation Controller NC), via a `view controllers` segue. VC1 is connected to VC2 via a `Show` segue. Item2 of the TBC should be linked directly to CV2 (via `view controllers` segue).

```
TBC - Item1 -> NC -> VC1 +> VC2
        |                |
      Item2 -------------+
```

2 possibilities:

1. If I connect the TBC to VC2 using `view controllers` segue (like shown above), I loose my top screen navigation bar in VC2 (if Item2 is used), which would allow me to return to CV1 (which is desired).
2. If I make a second `view controllers` segue from TBC to VC1, I could create a custom class of UINavigationController, which could determine which segue (Item1 or Item2) was selected. If Item1 is selected, VC1 should be shown. If Item2 is selected, VC2 should be shown. First, I don't know how I can determine in my custom class of UINavigationController, how to determine which of the 2 segues was selected. Also the item icons and titles of Item1 and Items2 are identical (which is not desired!) and I don't see any possibility to change only icon/title of Item2 and leave icon/title of Item1 as it is.

How can I connect Item2 to VC2, keeping the VC2 navigation bar, and having a different than Item1 icon/title for Item2?

Answer (score 0):

You can use segue identifier to distinguish between two segues.

You can specify segue identifier by selecting segue and go to identifier id in right panel.

Comment: The Relationship segue `view controllers` doesn't provide an identifier possibility. However I need this segue in order to generate an item in the Tab Bar Controller.

Comment: you can give identifier by selecting segue and select attribute inspector panel in right side

Comment: Nope. As I said ... not for this segue. It shows `Not Applicable` and the panel is blank!

Comment: i think you take segue from view controller. if yes , take segue from item2 and item1 not from viewController.

Comment: It is the opposite. The segue from the VC1 is a `Show` segue. This, I can identify as you describe, and I don't take that one. I do take the segue from Item2, which is a Relations ship segue type `view controllers`. These cannot be identified.